# matlab: logically comparing two cell arrays

Tags: arrays, excel, matlab, parsing, boolean

I have an excel file from which I obtained two string arrays, `Titles` of dimension 6264x1 and another `Names` of dimension 45696x1. I want to create an output matrix of size 6264x45696 containing in the elements a 1 or 0, a 1 if `Titles` contains `Names`. [image: This is the output that I want.]

I think I want something along the lines of:

```
for (j in Names)
    for (k in Titles)
        if (Names[j] is in Titles[k])
            write to excel
        end
    end
end
```

But I don't know what functions I should use to achieve what I have in the picture. Here is what I have come up with:

```
[~,Title] = xlsread('exp1.xlsx',1,'A3:A6266','basic');
[~,Name] = xlsread('exp1.xlsx',2,'B3:B45698','basic');
A = cellstr(Title);
GN = cellstr(Name);
BinaryMatrix = false(45696,6264);
for i=1:1:45696
    for j=1:1:6264
        if (~isempty(ismember(A,GN)))
            BinaryMatrix(i,j)= true;        
        end
    end
end
```

the problem with this code is that it never finishes running, although there are no suggestions within matlab.

Comment: Try [parfor](https://cn.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfor.html;jsessionid=388480564a781c24478d76e8d627) instead of `for`  maybe a little trick.

Comment: @HunterJiang I get this output when using parfor in place of the first for, how do I reformat the if statement for usage with parfor?                                  
Error: The variable BinaryMatrix in a parfor cannot be classified.
See Parallel for Loops in MATLAB, "Overview".

Comment: @However, I found that your code seems to do the same things for a multiple of times. (always `A` and `GN`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use third output of `unique` to get numbers corresponding to each string element and use `bsxfun` to compare numbers.

```
GN = cellstr(Name);
A = cellstr(Title);
B = [ GN(:); A(:)];
[~,~,u]= unique(B);
BinaryaMatrix = bsxfun(@eq, u(1:numel(GN)),u(numel(GN)+1:end).');
```

Answer (score 1):

[`ismember`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) can handle cell arrays of character vectors. Its second output tells you the information you need, from which you can build the result using [`sparse`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) (it could also be done by preallocating and using [`sub2ind`):

```
[~, m] = ismember(Titles, Names);
BinaryMatrix = full(sparse(nonzeros(m), find(m), true, numel(Names), numel(Titles)));
```